# How to config twig and Timber to translate full twig templates with {% trans %} tags

Tags: wordpress, internationalization, twig, twig-extension, timber

I've been trying to make Timber render and translate templates with {% trans %} tags.

I created a .po tranlation file with poedit and Twig-Gettext-Extractor but cannot find a way to make it work with Timber. I added the i18n internationalization extension to twig via Timber `get_twig` hook but I could not configure my wordpress theme to work. I tried different things from [twig docs](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/extensions/i18n.html) and [here](https://www.sitepoint.com/easy-multi-language-twig-apps-with-gettext/) without success.

Is there someone who uses Timber and twig templates with {% trans %} tags and wants to share its config?

Comment: I could setup twig by adding UTF-8 to my locale declaration `setlocale('fr_FR.UTF-8')`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Translating themes with Timber is not really different from the way you’d approach it when you’d develop a normal WordPress theme. You probably **don’t need any of the functionality provided by Twig’s i18n Extension**. You don’t have to work with `{% trans %}` tags either.

When I went to translate a Timber theme, I followed the Codex page about [Multilingual WordPress](https://codex.wordpress.org/Multilingual_WordPress) and the chapter about [Internationalization (i18n)](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/functionality/internationalization/) in the Theme Handbook. Since Timber version 1.x you can use most of the [common translation functions](https://codex.wordpress.org/L10n) right in your Twig files. There’s a section about using those in the [Text Cookbook in the Timber Documentation](http://timber.github.io/timber/#internationalization).

I guess the only thing you have to make sure when you already have your `.po` and `.mo` files in the `languages` folder of your theme is that you properly use [`load_theme_textdomain`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/load_theme_textdomain).

Comment: You're right, after having been able to configure Timber so it can parse `{% trans %}` tags, I realized how Timber  and `{{ __() }}` tags were much better suitable in WordPress environments.